# Unknown command tcip in ADB

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I am trying to connect my phone to Android Studio wirelessly but when attempting to make my phone to listen to port 5555 by using the command ADB TCIP 5555, I am getting the following error:
adb: unknown command tcip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is `adb tcpip <port>`.

Try running `adb tcpip 5555`

Answer (score 0):

It should be [`tcpip`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#wireless):

```
adb tcpip 5555
```